# Rails 4: How to check validation errors from inside a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some basic model validations that are triggered when a form gets submitted by AJAX. If the validations fail, I want to pass the validation errors back to the view so I can tell the user.

```
  def save
    logger.debug( params )
    @video = Video.new( video_params )
    if @video.save
        render json: @video
    else
        render json: errors.messages
    end
  end
```

This throws an error because `errors` is undefined. What am I doing wrong? I read [the docs on this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) and it only shows `errors.messages` used in the view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

errors is a instance method from an `ActiveRecord`. The correct way to use in your case is like this:

```
@video.errors.messages
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of ***messages*** use **full_messages**, like below

```
@video.errors.full_messages
```